# How many tennis players have announced retirement after winning Grand Slam?

Tags: trivia, tennis

Flavia Pennetta has announced the retirement after winning her first Grand Slam of the career.

I guess she is the only tennis player who has taken retirement after winning major.
Can you remember any other player or star who took retirement after achieving such kind of milestone in his career or he/she took retirement when he was at the top in his/her career?

Answer (score 4):

While he didn't announce it like Pennetta did - Pete Sampras decided to retire a few months after defeating Andre Agassi in the 2002 US Open Final for his final match as a pro. It was the same opponent in the same tournament where Sampras won his first major title too - against Agassi in 1990.

Marion Bartoli also retired from tennis very shortly after winning Wimbledon in 2013. She only competed in 3 matches after winning the Wimbledon title before announcing her retirement.